# Custom module import error only during deployment

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a very simple Flask app structured like this:

```
Dockerfile
requirements.txt
caller --> app.py
       --> user.py
       --> templates
       --> static
```

I am initializing and running my `Flask` app in `app.py`:

**app.py**

```
from twilio.rest import Client 
import sys, os
...
from user import User, Anonymous   
app = Flask(__name__)
...
def create_app():
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5005)
```

When I run my app locally, it's working fine but when I am trying to make an image and run the image, it's giving me an error:

```
  File "/caller/caller/app.py", line 11, in <module>
    from user import User, Anonymous
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'user'
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7.5-slim-buster


ENV INSTALL_PATH /caller
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install flask_login

COPY . .

CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --access-logfile - "caller.app"
```

**user.py**

```
import uuid

class User():
  ...


class Anonymous():
  ...
```

do you know how can I fix this issue? It's also my first `Dockerfile` and it's probably the issue. To build and run the image I am doing `docker build -t foo . && docker run -it foo`

Comment: Maybe `from .user import User, Anonymous`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's import system works by searching for modules in a list of paths defined by the interpreter. You can see this list by checking `sys.path`. If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path), the first item at `path[0]` is the directory containing the script you invoked the interpreter from.

You're invoking Python by running `gunicorn` from your working directory `/caller` that you set in your Dockerfile. So that's the base directory Python is using in `path[0]` for the import system. So when the line `from user import User, Anonymous` is hit, Python is trying to import it from `/caller`, which contains your Dockerfile, requirements.txt, and the /caller/ directory you copied in (via `COPY . .` in your Dockerfile). So the package is located at `/caller/caller/user.py` instead of `/caller/user.py`...the import system doesn't see it and you get your error.

**2 ways you can fix:**

**1.** Change your code to use a relative import. This will tell the Python import system to look in the same directory:

`from .user import User, Anonymous`

**2.** You can also fix it by changing your Dockerfile to copy the contents of `/caller` to the `/caller` working directory in the container, instead of the recursive `COPY . .` call you do that copies everything in.

Replace `COPY . .` with `COPY caller .` and update `gunicorn` to invoke just `app` instead of `caller.app` (since it's no longer nested in the 2nd caller directory).

Now, user.py will be located at `/caller/user.py` in your container, and the Python import system will find it when it checks `sys.path[0]`